# is there a way to filter an array of objects based on multiple checkbox values on checked change

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, checkbox

I Have this array I wants to filter based on checkbox checked values Using React.

```
const invoice = [
  {
    id: "RT3080",
    createdAt: "2021-08-18",
    paymentDue: "2021-08-19",
    description: "Re-branding",
    paymentTerms: 1,
    clientName: "Jensen Huang",
    clientEmail: "jensenh@mail.com",
    status: "paid",
  },
  {
    id: "XM9141",
    createdAt: "2021-08-21",
    paymentDue: "2021-09-20",
    description: "Graphic Design",
    paymentTerms: 30,
    clientName: "Alex Grim",
    clientEmail: "alexgrim@mail.com",
    status: "pending",
  },
  {
    id: "RG0314",
    createdAt: "2021-09-24",
    paymentDue: "2021-10-01",
    description: "Website Redesign",
    paymentTerms: 7,
    clientName: "John Morrison",
    clientEmail: "jm@myco.com",
    status: "paid",
  },
  {
    id: "TY9141",
    createdAt: "2021-10-01",
    paymentDue: "2021-10-31",
    description: "Landing Page Design",
    paymentTerms: 30,
    clientName: "Thomas Wayne",
    clientEmail: "thomas@dc.com",
    status: "pending",
  },
  {
    id: "FV2353",
    createdAt: "2021-11-05",
    paymentDue: "2021-11-12",
    description: "Logo Re-design",
    paymentTerms: 7,
    clientName: "Anita Wainwright",
    clientEmail: "",
    status: "draft",
  },
];
```

I set up a useState as an object to store the objects i want to filter with which is this

```
 const [check, setcheck] = useState({
    paid: false,
    pend: false,
    draft: false,
  });
```

Then I added an onchange event handler to each checkbox that I created

```
<input
  checked={check.pend}
  onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
  type="checkbox"
  name="pend"
  value="pending"
/>;

<input
  checked={check.draft}
  onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
  type="checkbox"
  name="draft"
  value="draft"
/>;

<input
  checked={check.paid}
  onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
  type="checkbox"
  name="paid"
  value="paid"
/>;
```

The onChange event handler below

```
 const onChange = (e) => {
    setcheck({ ...check, [e.target.name]: e.target.checked });
  };
```

so the problem is this, I wanna filter the array of objects using the checkbox checked values i.e if the onChange is triggered i wanna run a function that will filter the array and return only where the status === checked checkbox value.

so i created an handleChange function which i later added to onchange function. so the function now looks like this

```
const onChange = (e) => {
    setcheck({ ...check, [e.target.name]: e.target.checked });
    handleChange(e);
  };
```

and the handleChange function it self

```
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    let tempInvoice = [...invoice];

    if (e.target.name === "pend" && e.target.checked === true) {
      tempInvoice = tempInvoice.filter((inv) => {
        return inv.status === e.target.value;
      });
    }
    if (e.target.name === "paid" && e.target.checked === true) {
      tempInvoice = tempInvoice.filter((inv) => inv.status === e.target.value);
    }
    if (e.target.name === "draft" && e.target.checked === true) {
      tempInvoice = tempInvoice.filter((inv) => inv.status === e.target.value);
    }
console.log(tempInvoice);
  };
```

With the Above information provided, my tempInvoice only logs out newly curent checked items. i.e if I checked the draft checkbox, it would only return array that has the status.draft . if I checked both draft and paid, It would only return the Array that has Paid in it and not both.
and I want this functionalities to work in a way that if I check both draft and paid. It should only return Array that the status of paid and draft.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"Write a title that summarizes the specific problem"_ - An unspecific question is not a specific problem.

Comment: Why do you have three separate `if`s that all do the same? `if(["pend", "paid", "draft"].includes(e.target.name) && e.target.checked) { ... }`

Comment: Am Literally new to Javscript and i couldnt think of that
You can help me refactor the handleChange function..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you use setCheck instead of setcheck.

```
const[check, setCheck] = useStage({});

const onChange = (e) => {
    const newCheck = { ...check, [e.target.name]: e.target.checked };
    setCheck(newCheck);
    handleChange(newCheck);
  };

 const handleChange = (check) => {
    let tempInvoice = [...invoice];

    //if none checked
    if(!check.pend && !check.paid && !check.draft) {
       console.log(tempInvoice);
       return;
    }

    //if all checked
    if(check.pend && check.paid && check.draft) {
       console.log(tempInvoice);
       return;
    }
   tempInvoice = invoice.filter((inv) => {
        return (inv.status === "pending" && check.pend)
              || (inv.status === "paid" && check.paid)
              || (inv.status === "draft" && check.draft);
      });
console.log(tempInvoice);
  };
```

Comment: Am Wowed, I tried this and it works
But there is a problem, if I check everything and uncheck everything, the tempInvoice returns an empty array

Comment: it still didnt work but have marked your solution as the answer and through your own solution i was able to refactor everything and get it working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Everything works as expected on the above code John Posted but if I check the checkboxes and Uncheck them. The filter Item returns an empty array but rather should have returned The Previous Array. So I added a little code to get back previous array.

```
const[check, setCheck] = useStage({});

const onChange = (e) => {
    const newCheck = { ...check, [e.target.name]: e.target.checked };
    setCheck(newCheck);
    handleChange(newCheck);
  };

 const handleChange = (check) => {
    let tempInvoice = [...invoice];

    
   
   tempInvoice = invoice.filter((inv) => {
        return (inv.status === "pending" && check.pend)
              || (inv.status === "paid" && check.paid)
              || (inv.status === "draft" && check.draft);
      });
 if (
      !check.pend &&
      !check.paid &&
      !check.draft &&
      invoice.length > 0
    ) {
      tempInvoice = [...invoice];
    }

console.log(tempInvoice);
  };
```

Comment: I do not think what you add is necessary, it must something else, I noticed you have this: currentInvoice

Comment: @JohnDing it was a mistake and it  as been corrected